# How to clear js array on ajax page reload

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a js that is drawing onto canvas, when a php session change occurs I have it changing the color value(this works).  Though upon every reload the speed keeps increasing.  How would I go about resetting the js so when the page reloads it is firing a fresh iteration of the array variables and it does not compound onto the next.

```
<style>

 body {
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}


  #iso {
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;

  }

  #isohold {
  top: 37.5%;
  left: 37.5%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  }

  #loghold {
  top: -5%;
  left: 0%;
  position: relative;
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  font-size: 12;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 5;
  display: visible;
  }
</style>

<div id="isohold">  
<canvas id="iso"></canvas>
<div id="loghold">Login</div>
</div>










  <?php
    session_start();         




    //3.1.4 if the user is logged in Greets the user with message     
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
   $colorin = 'rgba(81, 180, 200, 0.5)';    

    echo "
<script>
                 $(\"#loghold\").hide();   
</script>       
            ";
    }else{ 

      $colorin = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)';         



  };

      echo "  "; 



 ?>


<script>

'use strict';


var rn = function rn(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};
var ctx = iso.getContext('2d');

var _window = window;
var w = _window.innerWidth;
var h = _window.innerHeight;

var t = 10;
var arr = [];
var cn = 200;
var rad = 300;
var sp = rn(1, 5) / 10000;

iso.width = w;
iso.height = h;

while (~ ~ cn--) {
    var angle = rn(110, 359);

    arr = [].concat(arr, [{
        color: '<?php echo $colorin ?>',
        distortion: rn(15, 75),
        tmod: rn(5, 10),
        size: rn(15, 20),
        speed: 0.0005,
        angle: angle,
        lastPos: {
            x: w / 2,
            y: h / 2
        }
    }]);
}

var draw = function draw() {
    request = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        return draw();
    });
    t++;

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0,.1)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    var crad = rad * Math.sin(300);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
    arr.forEach(function (el) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = el.color;
        ctx.lineWidth = el.size;
        ctx.beginPath();

        var lastPos = el.angle - el.speed;
        var x = w / 2 + (crad + el.distortion * Math.sin(t / el.tmod)) * Math.cos(el.angle * 180 / Math.PI);
        var y = h / 2 + (crad + el.distortion * Math.sin(t / el.tmod)) * Math.sin(el.angle * 180 / Math.PI);

        ctx.moveTo(el.lastPos.x, el.lastPos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);

        el.lastPos = { x: x, y: y };
        el.angle = (el.angle + 0.0005) % 359;
        ctx.stroke();
    });
};

var resize = function resize() {
    iso.width = w = window.innerWidth;
    iso.height = h = window.innerHeight;
};

var request = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    return draw();
});
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    return resize();
});

</script>             

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loghold").click(function(){
        $("#loginholder").show();
        $("#loginholder").load("/halcyon/pages/login/loginscript.php");
        $("#controlremove").show();
    });

   });    
</script>
```

The ajax load is a simple

```
$("#isoholder").load("/halcyon/pages/iso/iso.php");
```

Comment: JavaScript has no persistence across page loads and the only variable from php seems to be the color. Don't see anything that would cause what you are experiencing from code shown

Comment: I am loading and reloading this page into a div via ajax, I am sure this makes a difference

Comment: Well that is definitely not the same as page reload for sure. Don't load the script each time. Not enough known about what exacrly is being loaded by ajax

Comment: That's not how things work here. Questions need to be self contained

Comment: I will edit the op to show entirety of page reload, nothing additional is being reloaded

Comment: I had the recommendation of adding ?reload=1 to the end of the ajax load calls but this did not work

Comment: What you probably want to do is set the script up in main page and only call specific necessary functions inside the `load()` success callback. Still not clear what is what here. If code shown gets loaded each time then you are adding multiple click handlers to the same element

Comment: I will try that, thank you for your time.